# Android task and back stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Suppose A is the main activity with default launch mode, and activity B has singleTask launch mode. Now, we launch the app and there is only one task in this app containing only one activity (activity A). What happens when A starts B? Two tasks or just one task?

My experiment shows that B is placed on top of A in the same task, while the developer guide says singleTask activities should always be started in a new task. So, what am I missing?

UPDATE #1: in my experiment, I run `adb shell dumpsys activity` to see the task information.

Comment: In your experiment, why do you think B is still in the same task as A?

Comment: Go thru this [link](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode)

Comment: @scottt I use `adb shell dumpsys activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Not always, only in certain situations. It's very rare really.
I've written a post on that topic that might help you out, check it out here: http://angrybyte.me/post/156362879355/android-tasks-and-back-stack

But long story short, when launching from `default`, you'll always get it **in the same task**.